# AWS Route 53 SOA Top Level Domain Mismatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, nameservers

I recently moved my DNS hosting to AWS Route 53 and created the hosted zone prior to transferring the domain. The top level domain for the site is `.com` and I have Name Server records for `.co.uk`, `.com`, `.net`, and `.org`. The SOA record is the same `.co.uk` as the corresponding NS record.

Should I change the SOA to match the corresponding `.com`? Are the default records for NS and SOA well chosen, or will I want to change those too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should leave the SOA records and NS records as they are.

It is recommended that you retain the defaults, only updating to update for the TTL values.

If you want to update the SOA, make a backup of the original value just in case.

More information about these record sets are available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/SOA-NSrecords.html)